# Access Violation Exception while accessing BackStack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a page named `Page1.xaml` and can access and be accessed from `Page2.xaml` and `Page3.xaml`.
 I don't want to turn back from `Page1` to `Page3` and just to `Page2`.

Now when I do this an exception occurs:

```
if (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
{

}
```

it is:`Attempted to read or write protected memory.`

Can someone please show me how can I simply do what I said above to work for both WP7 and WP8 (the msdn documentation talks about here and there, so I miss the point.)

**Update**: when I use `NavigationService.CanGoBack` the same error occurs: `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if there are items on the BackStack then you should use the [CanGoBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.cangoback%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property of the [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.page.navigationservice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
if(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    // logic
}
```

If you want to remove all of the entries of the BackStack then use the [RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.

```
while (NavigationService.CanGoBack) 
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```